# makefile: calculate a sum during a parallel build

Tags: linux, makefile

I can run parallel build with -jX and makefiles. However, is there a way to do an addition/increment of a variable when each build is running separately, but the makefile stores the summed value. This summed value would be number of passed builds versus failed builds.

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. If any of the parallel invocations fails the whole make fails. What are you trying to do with this number?

Comment: I plan to use makefile for regression test. I would like to highlight how many test passed and how many failed.

Comment: I think that's unlikely to work the way you want and isn't really using make for its strengths. There are any number of test frameworks that would probably suit this usage better to my mind.